# NODE JS - Forever starting path problems

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a server.js file defined as follows:

```
    var iniparser = require('iniparser');
    var inihost;
    var inidbuser;
    var inidbpass;
    var inidbname;


    var config = iniparser.parseSync('../setup_db/config.ini');
            inihost = config.db_hostname;
            inidbuser=config.db_username;
            inidbpass=config.db_password;
            inidbname=config.db_name;
.....
```

on reboot I have a crontab that should automatically forever starts the server:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/forever start /var/www/html/rubrica/chat/server.js
```

Interestingly if I launch the server from any directory with the complete path like:

```
forever start /var/www/html/rubrica/chat/server.js
```

the server starts just fine..if , however, i **run the SAME command from withtin the /root/.forever/** directory the server will give me the following error:

```
 ENOENT, no such file or directory '../setup_db/config.ini'
```

So whenever i reboot the machine I get that error...how is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `iniparser.parseSync()` is not relative to the current file like `require()` but rather the current working directory. Use:

```
var path = require('path');
var config = iniparser.parseSync(path.join(__dirname, '../setup_db/config.ini'));
```